# How come SSRS Contains or Like Expression not working?

Tags: reporting-services, power-bi-report-server, ssrs-expression

I'm using MS Power BI Report Builder, and I'm having trouble getting the "Contain" function to work with an IF statement. I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out what's wrong with my expression. It's been giving me some headaches, and I could really use some assistance.

```
=iif(First(Fields!test.Value, "Test"). Contains("Yes - Axon"), "Yes", "No")
=iif(First(Fields!test.Value, "Test"). Like("Yes - Axon"), "Yes", "No")
```

The "Contains" function, but it's acting all wonky. No matter what, it keeps giving me "No" as the result, even when the "test" column clearly contains "Yes - Axon". Can anyone take a look at the values below and help me figure out what's going on?
[image]

[image]
Thank you So much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression are using `FIRST()` so they will only check the first value `test.Value` in the `Test` data set. If you add a table to your report and drag the test field onto it, then set your expression **without the first()** in another second column, it should work.

So the expression just needs to look like this.

```
=IIF(
     Fields!test.Value.Contains("Yes - Axon"), 
     "Yes", 
     "No"
    )
```

There is no need to specify the scope of the expression as it will use the current context (in this case the current row)

---

**Quick demo**

---

I recreated your sample data with the following dataset query

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (test nvarchar(256))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('Yes - LR Appliances'),
('Yes - LR Appliances'),
('Yes - LR Appliances'),
('Yes - LR Appliances, Yes - Axon'),
('Yes - LR Appliances'),
('Yes - LR Appliances, Yes - Axon'),
('Yes - Customer VMs'),
('Yes - LR Appliances, Yes - Axon, Yes - LR Cloud'),
('Yes - LR Appliances, Yes - Axon, Yes - LR Cloud, Yes - Customer VMs'),
('Yes - LR Appliances, Yes - Axon, Yes - LR Cloud, Yes - Customer VMs'),
('Yes - LR Appliances, Yes - Axon, Yes - LR Cloud'),
('Yes - LR Appliances'),
('Yes - LR Appliances')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I created a blank report, added the above as a dataset query then added a table.

In the first column I simple used the `test` field.

In the 2nd column I set the expression to the expression I mentioned above.

```
=IIF(
     Fields!test.Value.Contains("Yes - Axon"), 
     "Yes", 
     "No"
    )
```

When I run the report, I get the results I would expect...

[image]

Here's a short 30 second GIF I recorded whilst I created this report. If you can't see it clearly, right-click the gif and open in new window, then you can maximise to see it clearly.

[image]

Comment: @Alen Schofield, Thank you for the response. I tried your way. when I remove "First", I will get an error message. Any idea why is that? 

The 'Value' expression for the textrun 'Textbox1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.
----------------------------
The definition of the report '' is invalid.
----------------------------
An error occurred during local report processing.

Comment: What is the exact expression you are now using?

Comment: @WeldaSudha - you'd also need to remove the Scope for the FIRST expression - `, "Test"`

Comment: @HannoverFist `"Test"` is my column name.  Sorry for the confusion, my dataset name and column name were also `"test"`. If you look at the 2nd picture that I attached, you will get an idea. Thank you

Comment: @AlanSchofield, I have added it the way you want it, now it is working but still giving me the answer "No". It should be Yes

`=iif(Fields!test.Value. Contains("Yes - Axon"), "Yes", "No")`

Comment: I've updated the  answer with a 30 second GIF showing you how I did it with your sample data.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help

Comment: @AlanSchofield This works, again, thank you so much for showing me on GIF.

Comment: You're welcome. If you post questions in future, please supply the sample data as text, better still, a short script to create the data. People are much more willing to help if they can copy/paste the data to replicate your problem. If not they have to type it out from the images like I did.